# Prime Power to $n$-th Power Ring Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $k$ be a field that contains $\Bbb{F}_p$ as a subfield [e.g., $k = \Bbb{F}_p(x)$]. For every positive integer $n$, show that the function $\varphi_n : k \to k$, given by $\varphi_n(a) = a^{p^n}$, is a ring homomorphism.

It's pretty easy to see that it maps $1$ to itself, and that it is multiplicative. However, I am having difficulty showing that $\varphi_n$ is additive. We want to show that $\varphi_n (a+b) = \varphi_n (a) + \varphi_n (b)$ or $(a+b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}$. Using the binomial theorem, we get

$$(a+b)^{p^n}  = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n} + \sum_{k=1}^{p^n-1} C(p^n,k) a^{p^n-k}b^{k}$$

Now, if either $a$ or $b$ were in $\Bbb{F}_n$, then the result would follow, since $C(p^n,k)$ is divisible by and so either $C(p^n,k) a^{p^n-k} = 0$ or $C(p^n,k)b^k =0$. But what I shall I do if $a$ and $b$ are not in $\Bbb{F}_p$; I am not sure how to do deal with this case. I could use a hint.

Comment: Have a look at 'Freshman's dream'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prove that $C(p^n,k)$ is a multiple of $p$ for each $k=1,...,p^n-1$, because since the field has characteristic $p$, i.e. contains $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ is zero in the field, and hence so is any multiple of $p$. It will follow that $\sum_{k=1}^{p^n-1}{C(p^n,k)a^kb^{p^n-k}}=0$, and hence $\varphi_n(a+b)=\varphi_n(a)+\varphi_n(b)$.

Comment: Oh! Because every subfield's multiplicative identity is the same as the parent field, and so the multiplicative identity of $k$ is the same as $\Bbb{F}_p$'s, which has characteristic $p$. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, if an element $e$ of a field $k$ is a multiplicative identity for some subring $R$ of $k$, then for any non-zero $r\in R$, $er=r$. So dividing out by $r$ in $k$ gives that $e=1$, i.e. $e$ is the multiplicative identity of $k$. Hence if $k$ contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ then $k$ has characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* It is enough to prove for $n=1$ because $\varphi_n= \varphi_1 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_1$.